# getting values from optional object (Array of dictionary)?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

i've been trying to get "name" from response using

```
if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {

        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])  as? [String : AnyObject]
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
return nil


for field in dict?["report_data"]?["name"] as? [Any] ?? [] {
    print(field)                   
}
```

with no success.

Response is

> Optional({"content": "", "subject": "Weekly Attendance 2018-05-14 - 2018-05-20", "attachments": "[]", "report_data": "[{\"name\":\"Total Days\",\"value\":\"7\"},{\"name\":\"Present Days\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"Total Hours\",\"value\":\".0\"},{\"name\":\"Average Hours\",\"value\":\".0\"},{\"name\":\"Start Date\",\"value\":\"2018-05-14\"},{\"name\":\"End Date\",\"value\":\"2018-05-20\"}]", "asset_reference": "[]", "activity_reference": "[]", "form_approval_field_reference": "[]"})

Plz help me out with this.

Comment: From where did you get the `text`?

Comment: to avoid optional use (!), if let or guard statements

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are getting the response as dictionary of type `[String : [[String : String]]]`. So the `value` of `"report_data"` key is an array of type `[[String : String]]`.

Now `[[String : String]]` is actually an array of dictionary. So each element of the array is a dictionary that is `[String : String]` where your `"name"` key is resided.

```
let responseDictionary: [String : Any] = [ "report_data" : [
    ["name":"Total Days","value":"7"],
    ["name":"Present Days","value":"0"],
    ["name":"Total Hours","value":".0"],
    ["name":"Average Hours","value":".0"],
    ["name":"Start Date","value":"2018-05-14"],
    ["name":"End Date","value":"2018-05-20"]
] ]

if let arrayOfDictionary = responseDictionary["report_data"] as? [[String : String]] {
    for dictionary in arrayOfDictionary {
        if let name = dictionary["name"] {
            print(name)
        }
    }
}
```

Well, `for dictionary in arrayOfDictionary` was giving you error because your response is actually of type `[String : Any]` when you get it. But you can't perform much operations when the value is of type `Any`. So you need to cast that `Any` to explicit type to be able to have concrete object. You need to first cast `Any` type array to your actual `[[String : String]]` type array.

---

---

**Edit:**
You are doomed with badly formatted **JSON**. That's why you are in trouble. Take a look below how to deal with `Dictionary` to `JSON`:

```
let responseDictionary: [String : Any] = [ "content": "",
                                       "subject": "Weekly Attendance 2018-05-14 - 2018-05-20",
                                       "attachments": "[]",
                                       "report_data" : [
                                            ["name":"Total Days","value":"7"],
                                            ["name":"Present Days","value":"0"],
                                            ["name":"Total Hours","value":".0"],
                                            ["name":"Average Hours","value":".0"],
                                            ["name":"Start Date","value":"2018-05-14"],
                                            ["name":"End Date","value":"2018-05-20"]
                                        ],
                                       "asset_reference": "[]",
                                       "activity_reference": "[]",
                                       "form_approval_field_reference": "[]"
                                    ]
```

You might have converted this dictionary to `JSON` and then to JSON String. But in the process you lost the JSON standard formatting. How this should be done:

```
var text: String = ""

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: responseDictionary, options: .prettyPrinted)
    text = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Now, if your `text` is a valid JSON string, you are good to go:

```
if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
    do {
        let response = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
        if let response = response, let arrayOfDictionary = response["report_data"] as? [[String : String]] {
            for dictionary in arrayOfDictionary {
                if let name = dictionary["name"] {
                    print(name)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Comment: that is the response im getting from server... is it array of dictionary?.. and why it is coming as optional.. im new to this

Comment: for dictionary in array  this line saying Anyobject doesnt confirm to protocal 'Sequence'

Comment: if let arrayOfDictionary = dict!["report_data"] as? [[String : String]] .. its not going into this if condition... plz help me

Comment: edited. its not coming as a array of dictionary. its printing like a string

Comment: Have you done JSON deserialization with the response you got? If not, please post the whole context where you are retrieving the data

Comment: Your `JSON` is badly formatted. As a result the `JSONSerialization.jsonObject...` doesn't succeed. You should get error printed in your console.

Answer (score 0):

```
func dataToJSON(data: Data) -> AnyObject? {

    do {        
        return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as AnyObject
    }
    catch let myJSONError {

        print(myJSONError)
    }
    return nil
}

if let list = self.dataToJSON(data: data) as? [Any] {

      // here is array
}

if let list = self.dataToJSON(data: data) as? [String: Any] {

      // here is dictionary
}
```